# Does the following inequality hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, calculus-of-variations

I'm studying on a Jurimetrics problem where I want to design an optimal responsibility allocation mechanism between plaintiffs and defendants. But I'm right now facing the following problem, and I just have no idea how to prove it after several strives:

$$\frac{(1-x)^{2}-(1-y)^{2}}{1-x}>$$
$$\frac{(1-x-a)^{2}-(1-y-b)^{2}}{1-x-a}，$$ where $$x\in\left( 0,1 \right),y\in\left( 0,1 \right)$$, $$1>(x+a)>0, 1>(y+b)>0$$ and $1>a>b>0$ ?

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some context. How did this question arise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This inequality is false if e.g. $$x=\frac{5}{8},y=\frac{15}{16},a= \frac{7}{8},b=\frac{3}{4}.$$
(Then the left-hand side of your inequality is $\dfrac{140}{384}$ while its right-hand side is $\dfrac{171}{384}$.)

---

With the additional condition that $1 > x + a > 0$ and $1 > y + b > 0$, the inequality is true. According to Mathematica:

[image]

---

Here is a "human" proof of the inequality
with the additional condition that $1 > x + a > 0$ and $1 > y + b > 0$:

Letting $U:=1-x$, $V:=1-y$, $u:=U-a$, $v:=V-b$, we reduce the inequality in question to the inequality
$$U-\frac{V^2}U>u-\frac{v^2}u \tag{1}$$
if $U>u>0$, $V>v>0$, and $U>V-v+u$.

The left-hand side of (1) is increasing in $U$. So, (1) reduces to the inequality
$$d:=V-v+u-\frac{V^2}{V-v+u}-\Big(u-\frac{v^2}u\Big)\ge0. \tag{2}$$
But
$$ d=\frac{(u - v)^2 (V-v)}{(V-v+u)u}\ge0,$$
and we are done.

*Remark:* Here we only used the conditions $U>V-v+u$, $V>v$, and $u>0$, which are equivalent to the conditions $a>b$, $a>0$, and $1>x+a$ (respectively). None of the conditions $x>0$, $b>0$, $a<1$, $x+a>0$, $1 > y + b > 0$ was used.

Comment: What conditions do x and y need to meet to make the above inequality true?

Comment: @S.M.Hao : That would be an additional question, and it should be posted separately (preferably elsewhere). A simplest answer to this additional question is tautological: the inequality will be true if and only if it is true. Probably, you want a more informative answer. So, if you decide to post your additional question separately, you should specify the terms in which you want the additional conditions to be expressed.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, I will reorganize the problem. the current page should be deleted  . thanks again!

Comment: @S.M.Hao : No, this page should not (and cannot) be deleted, as it has a valid answer to your question. Rather, let us have a closure here, and then you can work on an improved version of this question and perhaps post it separately.

Comment: you are right, thanks

Comment: Hi! Pinelis, I'm sorry, l have lost an important condition : 1>(x+a)>0, 1>(y+b)>0. I have revised the problem. I want to know whether the original inequality hold true at this time. (the liabilities should belong to (0,1), so  x+a and y+b should be smaller than 1 and greater than 0)

Comment: this is my fault , I lost an important condition when firstly posting the problem.

Comment: that's great, thanks!

Comment: A humble question: How did you find the counterexample?

Comment: @user7427029 : I used Mathematica's command FindInstance for that.